# Returning actual result from an Actor instead of Promise/Future

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-http

I'm trying to write an actor in Akka/Scala that calls an HTTP REST API and sends the result back to the calling actor. The API may returns a collection/vector of results that must first be converted to an internal vendor neutral format so that the vendor can be changed in future without much changes required on our code. Most of the code is working but I'm not sure how to unpack and send the inner vector.

This is the code I have and it returns a `Promise` to the invoking actor. What I would like to return is the actual vector that gets created in the final `map` operation:

```
class RESTActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with JsonSupport {

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))
  val http = Http(context.system)

  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case query: String => {
      val requester = sender
      var uri = Uri(Settings.autoCompleteURL).withQuery(Query(Map("query" -> query)))

      sender! http
        .singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, uri = uri))
        .flatMap(response =>
          response.status match {
            case status if status.isSuccess() => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[VendorResponse].map(_.result.map(x => VendorNeutralResponse(x.id, x.field)))

            case _ => response.entity.toStrict(5.seconds).map { entity =>
              val body = entity.data.decodeString("UTF-8")
              log.warning(errorMessage(response, body))
              Left(errorMessage(response, body))
            }

          })
    }

  }
```

The calling actor:

```
pathPrefix("search") {
          get {
            parameter("query") { query =>
              {
                complete(restActor.ask(query)) //Doesn't work as the reply is a promise

              }
            }
          }
        }
```

How do I change the above code in the RESTActor to send actual result back instead of a future or promise?

**Edit**: After changing the code based on my own research and suggestions from @michał and @cyrille-corpet, the following code works:

```
pathPrefix("search") {
          get {
            parameter("query") { query =>
              {
                onComplete(gisRouter.ask(query)) {
                  case Success(resp: Future[Vector[VendorNeutralResponse]]) => {
                    resp.map(println)
                    complete("ok")
                  }
                  case Failure(e) => complete(e.toString)
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
```

It seems like I'm still getting a `future` as a response from my Actor. How do I get the actor to respond with actual data and not a `Future`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onComplete` function, that takes a `Future[T]` as input, and returns a `Directive1[Try[T]]`, so you can use as following:

```
pathPrefix("search") {
  get {
    parameter("query") { query =>
      onComplete(restActor.ask(query)) {
        case Success(resp) => ...
        case Failure(e) => ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT** about the return from your actor, you should pipe the result of `http.singleRequest` to the sender, instead of telling it:

```
http.singleRequest(...).flatMap(...) pipeTo requester
```

That way, the actual tell (`!`) will be done only once the `Future` is resolved.

Comment: Hi..the code doesn't help. I still have to unpack a future inside onComplete..please refer to the update/Edit.

Comment: @MojoJojo the edit to the answer suggests you to pipe `Future` to the sender instead of returning Future as part of responce

Answer (score 1):

You can do it monadic-like using map:

```
pathPrefix("search") {
  get {
    parameter("query") { query =>
      restActor.ask(query) map {
        case Success(resp) => ...
        case Failure(e) => ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Currently your Actor responds with future. Try refactoring it so it does return unwrapped value instead:

```
class RESTActor extends Actor with ActorLogging with JsonSupport {

  final implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(context.system))
  val http = Http(context.system)

  import akka.pattern.pipe
  import context.dispatcher

  private def handleHttpResponse = {
    case status if status.isSuccess() => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[VendorResponse].map(_.result.map(x => VendorNeutralResponse(x.id, x.field)))

    case _ => response.entity.toStrict(5.seconds).map { entity =>
      val body = entity.data.decodeString("UTF-8")
      log.warning(errorMessage(response, body))
      Left(errorMessage(response, body))
    }

  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case query: String => {
      val requester = sender
      var uri = Uri(Settings.autoCompleteURL).withQuery(Query(Map("query" -> query)))

      http.singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, uri = uri)).flatMap(response =>
          response.status map handleHttpResponse ) pipeTo requester
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response...the code doesn't help - I still get a future back from the actor and have to map/flatmap it again..have updated the question with code.